# Display one item for each object in a single Firebase document field - FirebaseRecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a fragment that contains a FirebaseRecyclerView with data that comes from my Firebase Database.

Usually, my data are stored with the following architecture :

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- collection (collection)
           |
           --- document1 (document)
           |        |
           |        --- documentField: "Data1"
           |
           --- document2 (document)
           |        |
           |        --- documentField: "Data2"
           |
           --- document3 (document)
                    |
                    --- documentField: "Data3"
```

Then, I create an Adapter, a ViewHolder, an Item (XML) for my view and I use the following methods in my fragment :

```
// Configure RecyclerView
private void configureRecyclerView(){
    //Configure Adapter & RecyclerView
    this.MY_ADAPTER = new MY_ADAPTER(
            generateOptionsForAdapter(MY_QUERY),
            Glide.with(this), this);

    MY_ADAPTER.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            MY_RECYCLER_VIEW_Linked.smoothScrollToPosition(MY_ADAPTER.getItemCount()); // Scroll to bottom on new messages
        }
    });

    MY_RECYCLER_VIEW_Linked.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    MY_RECYCLER_VIEW_Linked.setAdapter(this.MY_ADAPTER);
}

// Create options for RecyclerView from a Query
private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MY_OBJECT> generateOptionsForAdapter(Query query){
    return new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MY_OBJECT>()
            .setQuery(query, MY_OBJECT.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();
}
```

But this time, my data architecture is the following :

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- collection (collection)
           |
           --- document1 (document)
           |        |
           |        --- documentField (List<Object>): "Data1"
           |                                        : "Data2"
           |                                        : "Data3"
```

And I can't make ''MY_QUERY'' refer to a document field (because it then would'nt be a Query), so I can't manage to adapt myself to this architecture. I would like to have 1 item in my FirebaseRecyclerView for each data (One that display Data1,the second for Data2 and so on).

Do someone have a clue on how to deal with this ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think this article might help, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10).

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reading my problem. I read your article but I think that it leads to the same problem for me : I know how to get a List<Data> as a document snapshot (or a list of), but not as a Query, so I can't use the generateOptionsForAdapter(Query query) method. Maybe that I can avoid this method, but then I don't know how to make a responsive FirebaseRecyclerView.