# FirebaseRecyclerView - make onBindViewHolder method create severals elements

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am creating a FirebaseRecyclerView.

I give to my FirebaseRecyclerView a Query that refers to objects from my FirestoreDatabase.

**But instead of having 1 element for each object, I want to create severals elements.**

Example of 1 object structure :

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- collection (collection)
           |
           --- document1 (document)
           |        |
           |        --- documentField (List<Object>): "Data1"
           |                                        : "Data2"
           |                                        : "Data3"
```

What I can do :

[View_I_Can_Do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A2IX.png)

What I want to do :

[View_I_Want_To_Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf0Pn.png)

NB : The number of ''Data'' is changing, so I can't design an itemView to match with an undefined number of  variables.

I suppose the solution is in the **onBindViewHolder** method, but I don't know how to make it works.

Don't hesitate to ask for more details if needed.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated, thanks in advance !

***Edit 01/21/2022*** :

I'm still stuck on this ...
I tried to give more detail in this question : [Display one item for each object in a single Firebase document field - FirebaseRecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559215/display-one-item-for-each-object-in-a-single-firebase-document-field-firebaser)
Maybe this is more explicit.

Comment: If that array, is an array of custom objects, then most likely this article, [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) might help you solve the problem.